# Selenium CSS selector :visible is not a valid selector

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I'm using Page Objects to map elements in a page, something like that:

```
public class MyPage {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css = "a[data-code=panel]:visible")
    private WebElement cpaneladmin;

    public MyPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    }
}
```

The problem is this `:visible` CSS selector. Aparently, Selenium does not support it. Is there a way to select only visible elements using xpath or another kind of CSS selector?

Thanks

Comment: `:visible` isn't a CSS selector, it's a Sizzle selector. That's your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@FindBy(css = "a[data-code=panel]")
private List<WebElement> cpaneladmin;
```

Then iterate through the elements until you find the one that is displayed.

```
public WebElement FindDisplayed(WebElements elements)
{
    foreach (WebElement element in elements)
    {
        if (element.isDisplayed()) // correct method: isDisplayed()
            return element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=977) should answer your question.

If you want to verify the element is visible another way, use element.IsDisplayed(), or use ExpectedConditions.

Comment: what can I do if I have two elements that matches the selector, one visible and other hidden?

Comment: Do the two elements happen to have a css value for being visible or hidden? That would be how you could differentiate. Have you also tried the :enabled selector?

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem,

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("selector_that_matches_one__or_more_elements"));
//do what ever you want with the elements in list
```

The above code will store all the visible elements that can be located by the provided selector.
Try using an `implicit wait` at the start of your code, for the above statements to be more effective.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When implicitly waiting, **findElements()** method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout(30 secs in the above case) is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I came on this question a bit late, but here's how I resolved it in C#:

```
private void AssertAdminIsVisible(OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver wd)
{
    OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(wd, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    var cpaneladmin = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(OpenQA.Selenium.By.CssSelector("a[data-code=panel]")));
    Assert.IsNotNull(cpaneladmin);
}
```

And for.NET, it comes from the "DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" NuGet package:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `:not([style*="display: none"])` as a workaround.