# Selenium WebDriver: clicking a visible button inside a row of a table

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My apology as this question is quite long.

To be more specific, I am trying to click on the Pencil icon (Edit button) that is shown on the 4th row

[image]

Here's the code I tried to execute:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Edit Row')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

And here's the HTML code
[image]

After I ran the selenium code, the driver actually clicked on the Edit button of the 1st row (Administration | NA) instead of the 4th. I found out that not only the 1st but other rows also have the same HTML code, only difference was that the Pencil/Edit button is hidden because I wasn't the one that created the values of that row.

I did try with the following code as well:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Edit Row')]")).click();
```

I then received the error

```
element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

It seems the driver was still looking at the hidden Edit button in the first row, instead of the obvious visible one in 4th.

Is there anyway that I could click on the Edit button based on the value instead of the row number? The reason is that in the future, the value I enter for testing may not end up in 4th but 1st or 10th row.

Last but not least, my Safari can't seem to run the JS Executor code, everytime I gave it a go, the following error returned:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 'undefined' is not a function (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Can someone shed some light on this for me as well?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152326/selenium-css-selector-visible-is-not-a-valid-selector

Comment: First off... don't use JSE. It will allow you to click on elements that a user can't interact with which you don't, in general, want. Does the pencil icon show only when you hover over that row or is it there all the time? It seems odd to me that only the 4th row is editable as it shows in your screenshot.

Comment: Hi JeffC, the 4th row is editable is because I created it while the others were added by other normal or power users so I don't actually have the right to edit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks murali and JeffC for the suggestions, I have managed to get the driver to click on the displayed Pencil with this:

```
List<WebElement> EditButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[title='Edit Row']"));

        for(WebElement button : EditButtons) {
         if(button.isDisplayed()) {
             button.click();
          }
        }
```

Although it only solved half of the issue, I am trying to click on the displayed Edit button based on the value next to it. If I create another row with the value of 'Test234' and if the row is placed under the 4th row, the Edit button of 'Test234' won't be clicked. Any suggestion? I tried this but it doesn't seem to work, driver still clicked on the first visible edit button it saw:

```
List<WebElement> EditButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[title='Edit Row']"));
String textvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'test456')]")).getText();

        for(WebElement button : EditButtons) {
         if(button.isDisplayed() && textvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("test456")) {
             button.click();
          }
        }
```

UPDATE: Alright, issue resolved, I switched back to use xpath instead of cssSelector, then modified Vagnesh's suggestion (Thanks Vagnesh !!) a bit and now the driver is clicking on the visible edit button next to the text I search for without going through the loop

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Enter my desired Text here')]/following::div//a[contains(@title,'Edit Row')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one edit icon displayed, the code below should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Edit Row']")).click();
```

I think the reason you were running into the hidden element issue is that you were using JSE to click on it. Selenium is designed to only interact with elements that are visible... the way a user would. JSE allows you to interact with elements that are NOT visible. There are reasons to use JSE but I don't believe this is one of them. Using JSE you were finding an element that matched your XPath that was not visible and then trying to click on it... thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the element based on the field text, so that it can find its corresponding edit link.

```
functional_area = "Business Development / Innovation"

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='xspTextComputedField'][contains(@text, '" + functional_area + "')]/following-sibling::div/a[contains(@title, 'Edit Row')]"));
```

You can make it more dynamic by parameterizing the text ex. Financial.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, thanks for the code, unfortunately, I received the error of 'Unable to locate element' :^(

Comment: Have you modified 'Financial' to 'Business Development' in my previous code? Anyway i have now modified the code to take the functional area as parameter. Please have your try.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go once in firefox and then try same xpath in firebug with firepath add-on.

Try to inspect xpath of the pencil icon. Only one maching element with no dynamic values in that, then you can and use it. Else evaluate this xapth

```
  //a[contains(@title, 'Edit Row')]
```

You can find one or more matching elements. Then try to find difference in one of attribute for required element. If you are able to create xpath by using that odd attribute then its on else go for List and in loop cross theck for that, then work on it.